# PL/SQL Program that uses a Cursor to Rank

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, cursor, oracle10g

I'm trying to use the SQL statement in here and put it into a cursor. Unfortunately, I am unable to use the Rank() function for this particular assignment.

```
CREATE or REPLACE PROCEDURE RankGPA
IS
  vSnum   student.snum%type;
  vSname  student.sname%type;
  vGPA    student.GPA%type;
  vMajor  student.major%type;
  CURSOR rankGPA_cursor IS
    SELECT s1.snum, s1.sname, s1.gpa, count( s2.gpa ) + 1 as rank, s1.major
    FROM students s1
    LEFT JOIN students s2
    ON s1.GPA < s2.GPA
    GROUP BY s1.snum, s1.sname, s1.gpa, s1.Major
    ORDER BY 4;
BEGIN 
  OPEN rankGPA_cursor;
  FETCH rankGPA_cursor INTO vSnum, vSname, vGPA, vMajor;
END;
```

I'm trying to get an output like this:

```
Rank SNUM  SNAME  GPA  MAJOR
**** ****  *****  ***  *****
1    101   Bob    4     ENGR
2    102   Cari   3.5   ENGL
```

Comment: You have have twice same alias for students table (LEFT JOIN students **s2**)

Comment: You're only fetching one row from the cursor, and you aren't doing anything with it. Where is the output supposed to go? Why are you using PL/SQL at all? And why are you unable to use `rank()` - you've been told not to, or you don't know how? What about other analytic functions?

Comment: I think I'm supposed to make a dbms_output. to get these values. I've been told not to use rank() or any other function. The hint we've gotten is to use a fetch to add a counter for the rank number. Once the fetch hits the highest GPA, it prints the ranking # and the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrasing in your comment is a bit confusing, but it sounds like they want you to have a local variable to act as the 'rank' by counting the rows as they are fetched, something like:

```
DECLARE
  counter pls_integer := 0;
  CURSOR rankGPA_cursor IS
    SELECT s.snum, s.sname, s.gpa, s.major
    FROM students s
    ORDER BY s.gpa DESC;
BEGIN 
  FOR rankGPA_row IN rankGPA_cursor LOOP
    counter := counter + 1;
    dbms_output.put_line(counter
      ||' '|| rankGPA_row.snum
      ||' '|| rankGPA_row.sname
      ||' '|| rankGPA_row.gpa
      ||' '|| rankGPA_row.major
    );
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Each time the loop the `counter` variable is increased. Because the cursor query is ordered by GPA *descending* the first row fetched has the highest GPA and the counter is 1 at that point.

Using `dbms_output` for this is bad practise as in the real world you won't know if the client has that enabled, and you have to do some work to format the printed results neatly. But then this is contrived anyway.

You also need to consider how you want to rank things if two students have the same GPA, which seems likely. This will currently rank tied students arbitrarily. You could change the `order by` clause to add, say, secondary sorting by name; but students with tied scores will still get different ranks. It's certainly possible to give them the same rank even with this method, by keeping track of the last-seen GPA and only incrementing the rank/counter if the new row's value is different form the previous one. I don't know what you're expected to produce though.

You can use any style of cursor for this; explicit or implicit, and with the cursor-for-loop or with explicit open-fetch in a loop-close if you prefer.

Comment: This was explained so well. Thank you for taking the time I learned a lot from this!

Answer (score 1):

I have executed the similar one for emp table. You can change it for students table :

1.Without rank over function :

```
SELECT x.ranking,ename,sal 
FROM  emp e,
    (
SELECT e2.empno, COUNT(*) AS 
      ranking  
FROM  emp e1,emp e2 WHERE e1.sal<=e2.sal
       GROUP BY  e2.empno
)x

WHERE e.empno=x.empno 
ORDER BY sal
```

2.With Rank over function :

```
SELECT  RANK () OVER (ORDER BY  sal DESC ) AS ranking ,empno,ename,sal

FROM emp
```

Note: If there are ties, you can use DENSE_RANK

```
SELECT  DENSE_RANK () OVER (ORDER BY  sal DESC ) AS ranking ,empno,ename,sal

FROM emp
```

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using `windowed functions`:

```
SELECT s1.snum, s1.sname, s1.gpa, s1.Major,RANK() OVER(ORDER BY s1.gpa) AS r
FROM students s1;
```

> From [RANK doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions123.htm):
>
> **RANK calculates the rank of a value in a group of values.** The return type is NUMBER.